# The F104 tail pipe is not parallel to the runaway when the aircraft taxi.What is the reason?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, jet-engine, military, engine-design

The tail section is upward for clearance or to vector up the engine exhaust that will help to rise the nose when the aircraft take-off?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the Design section of the [Wikipedia article on the F-104](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-104_Starfighter):

> The aft fuselage was elevated from the horizontal reference plane,
> resulting a "lifted" tail, and the nose was "drooped". This caused the
> aircraft to fly nose up, helping to minimize drag. As a result, the
> pitot tube, air inlet scoops, and engine thrust line were all canted
> slightly from centerline of the fuselage.